# How to select the 3 most recent rows using the date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using VIsual Studio 2010 with Microsoft SQL Server and I am trying to write a query that will retrun the (3) most recent records in the database by the date field. Here are the fields in the database with columns;

id | first_name | last_name | url | date

Here is the current query I am using but it only returns the single most recent entry;

```
SELECT        id, first_name, last_name, url, MAX(DISTINCT date) AS Expr1
FROM            tbl_paystubs
GROUP BY first_name
ORDER BY first_name
```

How do I return the (3) most recent instead of just (1)?

Comment: `Select Top 3`?? but if you use `MAX(DISTINCT date)` all the 3 results will have same value!! however, visual studio has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 id, first_name, last_name, url, date
FROM tbl_paystubs
ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: If this is what you wanted, then I don't think your question was very clear.  It looked like you wanted the top 3 dates for each id/first_name/last_name/url/date combination.  I'm confused.  Maybe it's me.

Comment: I read the question as much simpler ... "retrun the (3) most recent records in the database by the date field"

Answer (score 6):

You could find the max, then find the next date that is less than the max, then find the next date that is less than that max.  Using CTEs:

```
WITH firstDate(id, first_name, last_name, url, date) 
as 
(
    SELECT        id, first_name, last_name, url, MAX(DISTINCT date) AS Expr1
    FROM            tbl_paystubs
    GROUP BY t.first_name, t.id, t.last_name, t.url
),
secondDate(id, first_name,Last_name,url,date)
(
    SELECT        t.id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.url, MAX(t.date)
    FROM            tbl_paystubs t
    inner join firstDate f
    on f.id = t.id
    and f.first_Name = t.first_name
    and f.last_name = t.last_name
    and f.url = t.url 
    WHERE f.date > t.date
    GROUP BY t.first_name, t.id, t.last_name, t.url
),
thirdDate(id, first_name,Last_name,url,date)
(
    SELECT        t.id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.url, MAX(t.date)
    FROM            tbl_paystubs t
    inner join secondDate s
    on s.id = t.id
    and s.first_Name = t.first_name
    and s.last_name = t.last_name
    and s.url = t.url 
    WHERE s.date > t.date
    GROUP BY t.first_name, t.id, t.last_name, t.url
)

   select f.id, 
          f.first_name, 
          f.last_name, 
          f.url, 
          f.date as "FirstMax", 
          s.date as "SecondMax", 
          t.date as "ThirdMax"
   from FirstDate f 
   left outer join SecondDate s
   on f.id = s.id
   and f.first_Name = s.first_name
   and f.last_name = s.last_name
   and f.url = s.url 
   left outer join ThirdDate t
   on f.id = t.id
   and f.first_Name = t.first_name
   and f.last_name = t.last_name
   and f.url = t.url
```

Comment: Down vote without a comment?  Come on ya'll, have some respect.

Comment: +1 for the solution and dont worry pal people down vote here just for fun.

Comment: an elegant solution ... maybe more than what OP was looking for ... might be useful elsewhere

Comment: like it, cte is when i usually use complexity with dynamic query's.

Comment: You have my +1, because initially I thought he is looking for top3 'per ID and date', too.

Comment: down voting for fun? maybe I angered someone in a different thread lol

Answer (score 2):

could try

```
SELECT TOP 3  id, first_name, last_name, url, date
FROM            tbl_paystubs
ORDER BY date desc
```

just re-looked at your code and noticed the Max(date), best thing to do and simple thing to do is to just order and select top 3

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is as follows:

```
;with cte as(
SELECT       *
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [date] order by [date]) as seq
FROM            tbl_paystubs
)
select Top 3 * from cte where seq= 1
```

Window function inside a CTE and then extract only the TOP 3 records

UPDATE: I missunderstood the question and I thought that the OP is looking for 3 records in 3 different days.